# Using KeyDown event for single action

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, keydown

I am trying to use the KeyDown-Event (because I like to use KeyCode) to make a single action happen. For this purpose I am using a bool variable to stop continuous actions.

Can't figure out what's wrong with my code though, and haven't found a comparable problem/solution yet...

There are 2 tabs on my tabcontrol and i want to be able to switch between them using CTRL+TAB.
The switching should happen ONCE on keydown of tab.

```
    bool tabSwitchPossible = true;

    void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            tabSwitchPossible = true; //Reset boolean
    }

    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabSwitchPossible && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            tabSwitchPossible = false; //Set boolean to prevent further action
            if (mainTabControl.SelectedIndex >= mainTabControl.TabCount - 1)
                mainTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
            else
                mainTabControl.SelectedIndex++;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Is there an automatic KeyUp event fired, even when i don't release the key?!

Thanks, in advance guys...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle Form1_KeyUp and tabSwitchPossible varible, remove it and just copy the following code:

```
    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (mainTabControl.SelectedIndex >= mainTabControl.TabCount - 1)
                mainTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
            else
                mainTabControl.SelectedIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was my exact first attempt... worked on the first time i pressed both buttons. (Just once - every run) Then it didn't work anymore. That is why i added keyUp and the bool.

Comment: It is working for me every time, please check the focus is in your application while you press keys.

Comment: Well it seems to be working, when i have exactly 3 three tabs, on the control. Just that it moves backwards. But when there are more or less than 3 tabs it jumps around seemingly random

Comment: There is no reason for such odd behavior, it should work as expected for any (n) no of tabs. I tested it for 2,3,5 tabs its working fine.

Comment: Solution: No code at all is needed since tabControl already implements switching between tabs via CTRL+TAB and CTRL+SHIFT+TAB. Your code is being ignored by the program, because you dont have Form1.KeyPreview activated. My code collides with the already implemented function.